# avconv on debian jessie throws error when trying to convert raw video to mp4

Tags: ffmpeg, avconv

I am trying to convert a raw video captured using a Logitech USB Cam(YUYV) to mp4 using avconv. I have tried the below to do so:

```
avconv -i out.raw -c copy output.mp4
avconv -i out.raw -vcodec copy -acodec copy output.mp4
```

but I get an error as shown below.

```
root@beaglebone:~/BBB_CV/boneCV# avconv -i out.raw -c copy output.mp4
avconv version 11.9-6:11.9-1~deb8u1, Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the Libav developersbuilt on Apr 23 2017 23:00:54 with gcc 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10)
out.raw: Invalid data found when processing input
```

I have checked [here](https://wiki.debian.org/ffmpeg), but did not find any relevant examples for the above purpose.

Edit: Added more details--

I tried doing the below by adding the infile options as suggested:

```
root@beaglebone:~/BBB_CV/boneCV# avconv -s 640x480 -framerate 30 -pix_fmt yuyv422 -f rawvideo -i out.raw -c copy output.mp4
```

This got me rid of the previous error and some new ones popped up as shown below.

```
root@beaglebone:~/BBB_CV/boneCV# avconv -s 640x480 -framerate 30 -pix_fmt yuyv422 -f rawvideo -i out.raw -c copy output.mp4
avconv version 11.9-6:11.9-1~deb8u1, Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the Libav 
developers built on Apr 23 2017 23:00:54 with gcc 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10)
[rawvideo @ 0x17e21c0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, rawvideo, from 'out.raw':
Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
Stream #0.0: Video: rawvideo, yuyv422, 640x480, 30 tbn
[mp4 @ 0x17eb840] Codec for stream 0 does not use global headers but 
container format requires global headers
[mp4 @ 0x17eb840] track 0: could not find tag, codec not currently 
supported in container
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
Metadata:
encoder         : Lavf56.1.0
Stream #0.0: Video: rawvideo, yuyv422, 640x480, q=2-31, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): 
Operation not permitted
```

The output.mp4 is being generated but when tried to open it throws an error.

Edit: I ran a "sudo apt-get install libav-tools" an then tried. This is what I got.

```
root@beaglebone:~/BBB_CV/boneCV# avconv -s 640x480 -framerate 30 -pix_fmt 
yuyv422 -f rawvideo -i out.raw -c copy output.mp4
ffmpeg version 2.6.9 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10)
configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-cflags='-g -O2 -fstack-protector-
 strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security ' --extra-ldflags='-Wl,-z,relro' 
   -cc='ccache cc' --enable-shared --enable-libmp3lame --enable-gpl --enable-
    nonfree --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-libfaac --enable-
    libxvid --enable-postproc --enable-x11grab --enable-libgsm --enable-
    libtheora --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-
    libx264 --enable-libspeex --enable-nonfree --disable-stripping --enable-
    libvpx --enable-libschroedinger --disable-encoder=libschroedinger --
    enable-version3 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-avfilter -
    enable-libfreetype --enable-libvo-aacenc --disable-decoder=amrnb --enable-
   libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libaacplus --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -
   -disable-vda --enable-libbluray --enable-libcdio --enable-gnutls --enable-
   frei0r --enable-openssl --enable-libass --enable-libopus --enable-
   fontconfig --enable-libpulse --disable-mips32r2 --disable-mipsdspr1 --
   disable-mipsdspr2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libzvbi --enable-avresample 
   --disable-htmlpages --disable-podpages --enable-libutvideo --enable-
   libfdk-aac --enable-libx265 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libdc1394 --
   disable-altivec --shlibdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
   libavutil      54. 20.100 / 54. 20.100
   libavcodec     56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
   libavformat    56. 25.101 / 56. 25.101
   libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
   libavfilter     5. 11.102 /  5. 11.102
   libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
   libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
   libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
   libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
  [rawvideo @ 0x18465e0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be 
   inaccurate
   Input #0, rawvideo, from 'out.raw':
   Duration: 00:00:00.10, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 146626 kb/s
   Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 640x480, 147456 
   kb/s, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
   [mp4 @ 0x184f790] Could not find tag for codec rawvideo in stream #0, 
   codec not currently supported in container
   Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
   Metadata:
   encoder         : Lavf56.25.101
   Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 640x480, q=2-
   31, 147456 kb/s, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
   Stream mapping:
   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
   Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): 
   Invalid argument
```

I ran "ffmpeg -s 640x480 -framerate 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f rawvideo -i out.raw output.mp4" and below is what I got.

```
root@beaglebone:~/BBB_CV/boneCV# ffmpeg -s 640x480 -framerate 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f rawvideo -i out.raw output.mp4
ffmpeg version 2.6.9 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-cflags='-g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security ' --extra-ldflags='-Wl,-z,relro' --cc='ccache cc' --enable-shared --enable-libmp3lame --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-libfaac --enable-libxvid --enable-postproc --enable-x11grab --enable-libgsm --enable-libtheora --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libx264 --enable-libspeex --enable-nonfree --disable-stripping --enable-libvpx --enable-libschroedinger --disable-encoder=libschroedinger --enable-version3 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-avfilter --enable-libfreetype --enable-libvo-aacenc --disable-decoder=amrnb --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libaacplus --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf --disable-vda --enable-libbluray --enable-libcdio --enable-gnutls --enable-frei0r --enable-openssl --enable-libass --enable-libopus --enable-fontconfig --enable-libpulse --disable-mips32r2 --disable-mipsdspr1 --disable-mipsdspr2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libzvbi --enable-avresample --disable-htmlpages --disable-podpages --enable-libutvideo --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libx265 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libdc1394 --disable-altivec --shlibdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
  libavutil      54. 20.100 / 54. 20.100
  libavcodec     56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavformat    56. 25.101 / 56. 25.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 11.102 /  5. 11.102
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[rawvideo @ 0x1d55e0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, rawvideo, from 'out.raw':
  Duration: 00:00:00.13, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 109969 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, 640x480, 110592 kb/s, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
[libx264 @ 0x1df6c0] using cpu capabilities: ARMv6 NEON
[libx264 @ 0x1df6c0] profile High, level 3.0
[libx264 @ 0x1df6c0] 264 - core 146 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=1 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.25.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 640x480, q=-1--1, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.26.100 libx264
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[rawvideo @ 0x1de3a0] Invalid buffer size, packet size 450428 < expected frame_size 460800
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid argument
frame=    3 fps=1.7 q=29.0 Lsize=     263kB time=00:00:00.03 bitrate=64692.6kbits/s    
video:262kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.318205%
[libx264 @ 0x1df6c0] frame I:1     Avg QP:33.09  size:100676
[libx264 @ 0x1df6c0] frame P:2     Avg QP:32.99  size: 83672
[libx264 @ 0x1df6c0] mb I  I16..4:  0.0% 95.4%  4.6%
[libx264 @ 0x1df6c0] mb P  I16..4:  0.0% 45.7%  3.0%  P16..4: 35.9% 10.7%  4.8%  0.0%  0.0%    skip: 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x1df6c0] 8x8 transform intra:94.6% inter:86.1%
[libx264 @ 0x1df6c0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 100.0% 100.0% 100.0% inter: 53.6% 100.0% 100.0%
[libx264 @ 0x1df6c0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 56% 12% 24%  2%  0%  1%  1%  2%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x1df6c0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 82% 11%  4%  0%  0%  0%  1%  0%  1%
[libx264 @ 0x1df6c0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 48% 30% 14%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x1df6c0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x1df6c0] ref P L0: 83.5%  7.9%  8.6%
[libx264 @ 0x1df6c0] kb/s:21441.60
```

Comment: Note: `avconv` is not `ffmpeg`; it's from the Libav fork. The versions you are using are a little outdated. If you want to use the real ffmpeg, and a recent version, download a static build from here: http://ffmpeg.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the input is raw, avconv doesn't know input properties. It needs to register those into the MOOV box of the MP4 it creates. So, before `-i out.raw`, you need to specify `-s WxH -framerate N -pix_fmt P` where the values should be substituted in. YUYV will usually be `yuyv422`.

Comment: I tried this "avconv -s 640x480 -framerate 30 -pix_fmt yuyv422 -i out.raw -c copy output.mp4", yet getting the same error.

Comment: Add `-f rawvideo` as well.

Comment: I tried with "avconv -s 640x480 -framerate 30 -pix_fmt yuyv422 -f rawvideo -i out.raw -c copy output.mp4" and got some results. It was too big to paste it here, so I have updated it in the question. Now it generates output file but still, some issues exist and unable to play the mp4 file.

Comment: Upgrade to a recent version of ffmpeg. Yours is too old to support rawvideo in MP4.

Comment: I ran a "sudo apt-get install libav-tools" and then tried. Yet it shows codec not supported. This time the output slightly differs from previous one but issue still exists. Is there any other way to upgrade or work around for this?

Comment: Now I use "ffmpeg -s 640x480 -framerate 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f rawvideo -i out.raw output.mp4" and able to open the file, but file size is too small like 256 KB. I have pasted the output in my question, is that supposed to be the expected response?

Comment: And also getting an error like this "Invalid buffer size, packet size 450428 < expected frame_size 460800
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid argument". How to get rid of this.

Comment: @VinayDivakar The version you're running is still rather old.

Comment: Why don't you just get the binary from the link I posted above?

Comment: That buffer size msg is because the last frame of your input is truncated.

Comment: @slhck, I did a "git clone https://git.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git ffmpeg" and then within the ffmpeg directory, I ran "./configure --prefix=/usr" and "time make -j 8". Then I tried the conversion using "ffmpeg -s 640x480 -framerate 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f rawvideo -i out.raw output.mp4", but still the same issue exists.

Comment: @slhck, problem solved. Now I am able to convert the raw video and play it in mp4 format. Thanks!